# How can we prove that $3t$ cannot be a perfect cube for any integer $t$ except 9?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

If $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ then prove that $3t$ can never be a perfect cube except for $t=9$.

How can we prove things like these? I’m pretty new to Number-Theory and I find it difficult to prove things like these. Mathematical Induction cannot be used here because (beacuse the statement has an exception for $t=9$), even if we use a computer code then also it is not wise to iterate $t$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

If we try to use proof by contradiction, our main question just gets transformed:

Let’s say there exists a $t$ other than 9 such that $$3t = n^3$$ Well this means $$t=\frac{n^3}{3}$$ that is there exists a perfect cube which is divisible by 3 (other than 27). But how to prove that there doesn’t exist any perfect cube which is divisible by 3 (other than 27).

I just need a hint for how to proceed for proofs like these.

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove isn't true. 3 * 72 = 216 = 6^3.

Comment: What has your question to do with `perfect-numbers`?

Comment: You are trying to prove something wrong, take $t=9\cdot 8$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought perfect-numbers mean whose surds results in an integer.

Comment: No. Those are the perfect *powers*. A perfect number is a number which is equal to the sum of all of its divisors (except itself).

Comment: @Knight "Perfect square/cube/power/etc" (more commonly just called a square or cube number) is what you mean. A "perfect number" is a different kind of number related to what other numbers can divide it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Jam I have corrected the tags. Thanks for informing me about those things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the number $t=3^2a^3$,

We have $$3(3^2a^3)=3^3a^3=(3a)^3$$

Clearly $a$ need not be $1$, hence there are many $t$ that  make $3t$ a perfect cube.

Comment: Now, can we say $9a^3$ can never be a perfect cube? I think we cannot because for $a = 3b^6$ we will get $3a^3$ as a perfect cube, but we must make sure that $a$ is an integer.

Comment: @Knight I'd suggest searching for that question, and if it hasn't been asked previously, asking it separately. But in brief: How many copies of $3$ occurs in the prime factorization of $9 a^3?

Comment: @TravisWillse 2 copies.

Comment: Well, it depends on the number of copies of $3$ in the prime factorization of $a$.